# What is the meaning of these two? Donna Bangumi ga suki and Donna Bangumi o miru?

Tags: meaning

I already know what *"Donna bangumi ga suki?"* means: *"What is your favorite tv show?"*.

However, I'm less sure about *"Donna bangumi wo miru?"*. Does it mean *"What TV shows do you watch?"*? If so, would *"Watashi wa Sophia the First wo miru"* be a valid response?

Comment: なんでも日本語版は「ちいさなプリンセスソフィア」というらしいです。

Answer (score 2):

> would "Watashi wa Sophia the First wo miru" be a valid response?

That is a valid answer, but please note that [どんな means what kind](https://www.wasabi-jpn.com/japanese-grammar/japanese-wh-questions/), so your answer doesn't have to be a specific TV show. You could respond with a genre, general description, etc.

Comment: You could still use a particular instance as a representative of a kind or group by leveraging よう: 「Sophia the First」のようなばんぐみをみる。I watch programs such as "Sophia the First".